# After clicking logout button the previous url should not work

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery

I have a website on which when I click logout button the it redirects to Login page. Now I have 2 question maybe they are related:
Question 1: For Eg. my first page after login is:

```
https://travel.name.com/models/WebForm1.aspx?name=ishaan.g@abcd.com
```

So if I copy this URL and then click logout button it goes to login page. But when I paste the copied URL in browser it directly opens without asking for login.

Question 2: In the same url after 'name' if I change email id (meaning some other user mail id) it directly shows the data without asking for login.

I am trying to clear session but I have not sure that is right thing.

I have tried clearing session in javascript :

```
function clr_session() {
            sessionStorage.clear();
            window.location.href = "Login.aspx";
        }
```

Expected result is in both cases is:
Case 1: If I logout then the copied URL should lead to login page
Case 2: If I change email id in the URL then it should lead to login page

Thanks for help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue here is on the back end rather than the front. I'm not sure how you've implemented authentication on your back end, but when you open WebForm1.aspx, your server should check if the user is authenticated. If not, the server should redirect the user to the login page.

The server should also invalidate the user's session when the logout button is clicked.

Clearing sessionStorage on the front end is unlikely to do anything, as this is stored locally on the client and not sent to the server.

Comment: Sound more like a browser cache issue to me. I'd check if the request really gets sent.